# C# File.Exist(File_Path) Returns false even if File_Path is true, file exists and i have rights to access that file

Tags: c#

I'm writing a software which will run on Windows 7. I'm listing installed services, getting service's image path locations and checking if service file exists.(Dll or Exe).

I'm checking file locations with `File.Exist(File_Path)`. For some files, it returns `false` even if file path is `true`, file exists and I have rights to Access that file.

I know that even if that file exists, if the user don't have the rights to Access it `File.Exist(File_Path)` returns false.

For example, it returns true for the file `C:\Windows\System32\appmgmts.dll`
but it returns false for the file `C:\Windows\System32\audiosrv.dll`

And when I look user permissions for these 2 files under the Windows explorer, they are exactly same.
But `File.Exist(File_Path)` returns different answers for these files.

I'm running Visual Studio, and Exe file as an Administrator.

Please give me some advices for this strange behavior.

Comment: I suggest that you try [File.ReadAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes.aspx) on the file and then post the message of the resulting `IOException`. This might give you more information than the simple `False` of File.Exists.

Comment: Guess: your application is running in 32-bit mode on a 64-bit system. If so, what your program sees in C:\Windows\System32 is what Windows Explorer shows as C:\Windows\SysWOW64. You can check this by looking for (or creating) a file in C:\Windows\SysWOW64 that does *not* exist in C:\Windows\System32, and then attempting to open it from C:\Windows\System32.

Comment: try `File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "appmgmts.dll")` and `File.Exists(Path.Combine(Environment.SystemDirectory, "audiosrv.dll")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I exucute File.Exists in x86 configuration I have the same result, but when I am in 64 the two files returns true, and I found on the net that File.Exists in your case search in SysWOW64, check this question for more: [check if file exist on 64 bits system using File.Exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2160699/check-if-file-exist-on-64-bits-system-using-file-exists)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed a similar issue that occurred while checking files over a mapping that I created with my domain credentials. I was debugging VS as an Administrator. I was able to navigate through Windows Explorer to the file but not with VS.

I solved the problem when I closed VS Admin mode and started it normally back again.